# Time (minutes) difference between 2 dates MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, time

```
CREATE TABLE Test (

id int primary key,
Present varchar(10),
Date date,
Time time
);

INSERT INTO Test (id, Present, Date, Time)
Values (1, 'Present', '2018-07-18', '10:13:55' ),
(2, 'Present', '2018-07-18', '10:10:55' );
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
id,
Present,
Date,
Time,
current_time AS 'Current Time',
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, [Time], CURRENT_TIME()) AS 'Current Time'

FROM Test
```

I am looking to find the difference between time1 and the current time in minutes. I keep getting an error so i am assuming maybe its a conversion issue but i cant figure it out.

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/486850/47

Can anyone advise me thanks

Comment: do you want difference of date to be in minutes or just the time

Comment: @Sinto just the time. thats why i thought it would be better to use current_time(*) and not now()

Comment: Some thing like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/486850/72?

Comment: Square braces are used (predominantly) in SQL Server.  They are not recognized in MySQL.  Are you sure you have tagged the question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
id,
Present,
Date,
Time,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())

FROM Test
```

Is working, I guess your aliases are giving you a hard time

Comment: How could i get this to display at hour,min,second instead of just minute

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT 
id,
Present,
Date,
Time,
current_time as Current,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, Time, CURRENT_TIME()) AS Time_difference
FROM Test;
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/486850/72)